# Reconfiguring a dynamic library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, linker

I'm working with an open source library that's made available as a git repository ([XML-RPC](https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc)) and I'd like to use it in an iPad application. As I understand it, iOS applications should use static libraries for their linking.

Since this comes as a dynamic library, how can I convert it to something I can link with my app and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this in several steps:

First, I opened the library project in Xcode and created a new target for the static library. I then made a directory in the project folder called "XMLRPC" and moved all the header files to it. I deleted the now-red invalid references to the header files, and re-added them (but kept the box for copying them to the current folder unchecked).

I added this Xcode project to my main project with a relative reference. I opened my main app's target and added the library project as a direct dependency, and checked the "Always search user paths" option on my main app's target settings.

Lastly, I modified the general Xcode preferences to use a shared build directory. I haven't tried it without that since it was something I wanted anyways; it might not be necessary.

My revision control has two folders in it: one's my project, and the other's the library. The library is still under git control within mercurial; I'm hoping this doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe naive answer but why not just add all the relevent files in the repository to your app and just build it?

Put the files in a seperate folder obviously so you can update them to a newer version if you need to etc. Lots of projects I've done have an 'external' folder that just contains codethat I use from 3rd party sources. I've usually got the source so just compile it into my app and don't bother with making it a library.

Or are there tricky conditions that need to be met to compile this code?

Comment: well, this code is already in a managed xcode project. if i could maintain compatibility with the git repo that'd be a big plus

Comment: You can keep exactly the same folder structure as in their repository (I'd have it as a git submodule) - just add the required files in a group in your XCode project (without checking the box that says something like 'copy to this groups folder' when you add them so they don't move). Then you can just `git pull` to your hearts content to get the latest version. You're still building from source in your project and you get the benifit of easy updates and their XCode project should have unit tests in that you can run etc.

Comment: All right, I'm considering this. But shouldn't it still be possible to modify the binary output type of Xcode? This is just a workaround, albeit a functional one

Comment: I should have mentioned- I'm using mercurial